# Regexp match all pieces of a string with `[0-9_]+` and skip optional `_[a-z0-9]{24}`?

Tags: regex

Regexp match all pieces of a string with `[0-9_]+` and skip optional `_[a-z0-9]{24}` ?

For instance,

```
hello word some_stuff other_stuff_607eea770b6d00003d001579 something
```

Should only capture/match

```
hello word some_stuff other_stuff something
```

Here's what I have but it still matches some part of `[a-z0-9]{24}`

```
/[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)?(?:[a-z0-9]{24})?/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to match strings consisting of letters and underscores, whole words, with the end of the word at the end of the string, or a sequence of 24 more letters and/or numbers preceded by an underscore:

```
\b[a-z_]+(?=_[0-9a-z]{24}|\b)
```

Comment: Yep, that works!! Will validate when it let me...

Comment: Actually, no - I failed to notice you also want to match the starting bit of other_stuff_etc

Comment: Ah yea you're right, got too excited lmao

Comment: Fixed it - bit more complicated, but still quite straightforward, assuming your engine supports lookahead

Answer (score 1):

As you mention php in the comment of the accepted answer, you might also make use of a [SKIP FAIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) approach:

```
_[0-9a-z]{24}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*
```

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `_[0-9a-z]{24}` Match `_` and 24 repetitions of ranges 0-9a-z
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` The previous matched should not be part of the match result
- `|` or
- `[a-z]+` Match 1+ chars a-z
- `(?:_[a-z]+)*` Optionally repeat `_` and 1+ chars a-z

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bmpGnE/1) and a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/i46Wb)

Example code

```
$re = '/_[0-9a-z]{24}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*/';
$str = 'hello word some_stuff other_stuff_607eea770b6d00003d001579 something';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

var_export($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
array (
  0 => 'hello',
  1 => 'word',
  2 => 'some_stuff',
  3 => 'other_stuff',
  4 => 'something',
)
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about skip/fail, thanks for reply, upvoted.